# ROS Answers SE migration: compiling msg

Tags: custom-message, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

everytime, when I compile my package from scratch,

I have to comment out some lines in my CMakeList.txt

- addexecutable(file file.cpp )
- target_link_libraries(file {catkin_LIBRARIES} )

Afterwards it can compile my custom msg and then I include those lines and the project is ready to use.

What must I do that I can compile it as once?

regard,
Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230818/compiling-msg/) by [jester](https://answers.ros.org/users/25933/jester/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-03**:
Please edit your post and provide more information, such as your entire `CMakeLists.txt` file (without all the comments though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing a dependency on the message generation to make sure that the message generation runs before the executable tries to compile.

If you edit your post to show the compile error and your CMakeLists.txt we can probably help you more.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also think about your design. It's often useful to separate the message (service, action) definitions from your code and to create a *_msgs package. This can for example be useful if your code needs some special libraries or takes long to compile. If you now want to just have an action client on another computer, you'd have to fulfill all dependencies just to generate the message files. If however you have a separate msgs-package, you only have to compile the messages.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1